# Are sets actually implemented as maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, set

Everywhere on StackOverflow, I see the response:

> A `Set` is just a `Map`, except that it's `Key` is it's `Value`. This is why both `Set` and `Map` cannot have duplicates, as it violates the unique `Key` principle.

But then I see (for example) that `Set` does not involve itself with `Map` at all. Infact, `Map` isn't even part of `Collections` while `Set` is. But to me, this doesn't make sense because most likely the implementation of `HashSet` in the JDK is very similar to the implementation of `HashMap`, besides the fact that both come from different interfaces.

What is the relationship between `Set` and `Map` in this regard?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the source code will definitely help you. `Set` is indeed backed by some `Map`

Comment: Also, note that you shouldn't consider how `HashSet` or `TreeSet` are implemented and wonder why a *class backed by a Map should be considered a Collection*. Implementations can change, its the *functionality* that should be considered here.

Comment: Where did you find this image? Can I use? I'm doing a tutorial about collections framework, and I liked this example.

Comment: @diegocolli I found it on google images when searching "java collections". However you can find the image [here](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-Collections). It's a russian blog post apparently but it has other images relating to collections. Sorry I can't be more of a help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Set` and `Map` interfaces are not related (except of the `keySet()` and `entrySet()` methods of the `Map` interface that return `Set`s backed by the `Map`).

However, several `Set` implementations use a backing `Map` implementation to store their data (the elements of the `Set` become keys in the underlying `Map`, and the values of the underlying `Map` are just dummy objects). This is true for `HashSet` and `TreeSet`.

This is mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) :

> public class **HashSet**
> extends AbstractSet
> implements Set, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> This class implements the Set interface, **backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance)**.

[And](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) :

> public class **TreeSet**
> extends AbstractSet
> implements NavigableSet, Cloneable, Serializable
>
> A NavigableSet implementation **based on a TreeMap**.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Set interface is not backed by Map or anything. However, HashSet is implemented using Hashmap as actual data structure.

Set is not said to be having Map in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

However, as per [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) Hashset is using HashMap intertally to make sure unique data is maintained.

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element.

It keeps the value added to Set inside the Map as key, not in value. It adds same constant single object in values for all the entries.

```
  public boolean More ...add(E e) {
     return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Here, PRESENT  is static value dummy object to be kept  in backign Map.

```
  private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

Backing Map object gets created when we invoke  various construtors of HashSet :-

```
  public More ...HashSet() {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
   }
```

public More ...HashSet(Collection c) {
        map = new HashMap(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
        addAll(c);
 }

public More ...HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        map = new HashMap(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
  }

All the source can be seen at this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.0PRESENT)

Refer javadocs for other Set implementations backed by Map.